# Subversion: create a branch by merging two other branches

Tags: svn

I have two project branches branchA and branchB, both children of a common father branch. I want to create a new branchC which is the result of the merge of the two exinsting branches.

So I try

```
svn merge branchA@head branchB@head branchC
svn: E155010: The node 'project/branchC' was not found.
```

What is the best way achieve this task?

Answer (score 0):

What you tried seems wrong because:

1. You did not create the branch branchC before merging and so you don't have any working copy of branchC (which is needed for merging into branchC)
2. The command `svn merge branchA@head branchB@head branchC` merges the *difference* between branchA and branchB into branchC (and I think you want to merge branchA *and* branchB into branchC)

I suggest you the following solution:

1. Create the branch branchC by copy from trunk using `svn copy` command
2. Check-out the branchC
3. Merge branchA into your working copy of branchC using `svn merge branchA@head branchC`
4. Merge branchB into your working copy of branchC using `svn merge branchB@head branchC`
5. Resolve conflicts and commit on branchC